# Reposition text on a header to the left of the page html css codes

Tags: html, css, position

I am wondering if someone can please share with me the html and css code to move the header words "Michelle Lindemann's....Bringing your ..." over to the centre left hand side of the header as opposed to the middle. I have copied my current code below and I have also attached a screen shot of the page as I thought it may assist you. Thanks so much, I appreciate it. Michelle

```css
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
}


.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 47%;
}


.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .1rem black;

}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .6rem black;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 500;
    border-width: medium;
```

```html
  <div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="carousel-item active">
                     <img src="img/meheaderwordstwo.png">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h1 class="display-2"></h1>Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
                         <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
                         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm">DISCOVER MORE</a>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnhHh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Set text-align to left with `text-left` class on the `carousel-caption` class `<div>`.

```
<div class="carousel-caption text-left">
```

UPDATE: I have modified the code upon your change request. Please see the code snippets for change details.

1. h1 & h3 text black
2. button color change to black

```css
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 47%;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .1rem black;
  color: black; /* h1 color black */
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .6rem black;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black;  /* h3 color black */
}

.btn {
  font-weight: 500;
  border-width: medium;
}

/* Modify the btn-outline-dark color to black */
.btn-outline-dark {
  color: black !important;
  border-color: black !important;
}

.btn-outline-dark:hover {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
  border-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1009/1920/1080">
    <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
      <h1 class="display-2">Michelle Lindemann's Magical Stories</h1>
      <h3>Bringing your dreams to life!</h3>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ">DISCOVER MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer, I appreciate it. Can you please also share with me how I change the colour of the black for both h1 and h3 as well as, the button outline to black rather than light. thanks so much, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MichelleLindemann Please see the code snippets above for the change.